# How can I disable nodejs ChildProcess.spawn stdout buffer?

Tags: node.js, buffer, spawn

I'm trying to intercept `compass watch` output using the following code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('compass', ['watch'], { cwd: process.cwd() });

process.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('[log] ' + data);
});
```

My problem is: I have to save the file twice for the overwrite message to come out in stdout. Here's a sample output...

after `node compass.js`

```
[log] >>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
```

after I've saved the file

```
[log] >>> Change detected at 20:17:19 to: components/_avatar.scss
```

after I save the file for the second time

```
[log] overwrite assets/css/modules/projects.css 
>>> Change detected at 20:17:26 to: components/_avatar.scss
```

It looks like the "overwrite assets/css/modules/projects.css" is being buffered. Is there any way I can avoid this buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I just found out, compass (or perhaps OSX) is the real culprit. If I run `compass watch` the output is instantly updated. But, if I run `compass watch > out.log` the same behaviour observed with node occurs.